# CodeIgniter configure different IP for READ and WRITE MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, master-slave

My company has been setting up a different server for read and write access of mysql DB. Previously, we use custom php script.
However, I was recently given task to create tools by leveraging CI. I've done it on test server. Now, I'm confused, how to implement it on live server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup multiple 'connection groups' for each server in your database.php config file, then in the Model:

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('group_one', TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('group_two', TRUE);

//read from DB1
$DB1->query();

//write to DB2
$DB2->insert();
```

See examples in: [Connecting to Multiple Databases](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Might it be easier, rather than doing this by IP, do it using MySQL users.

You could have two different users, one with all the write privileges like `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, then another user with all the READ privileges like `SELECT`, or what ever you wish.

Then what ever code is running on your write web server uses the write user and vice-a-versa?

Comment: can you elaborate more? because, we have different server for read and write. From what you write, I think that only apply to single server, CMIIW

Comment: I am confused as to what your setup is now - perhaps rewrite your question?