# Load test with 4000 Concurrent users

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, rds

I am using CodeIgniter for my API implementation. Please find the server resources and technologies used as follows :

**SUMMARY**

```
Framework : CodeIgniter

Database : MySQL (Hosted on RDS)

Hosting :  AWS t2.Micro

Web Server  : Nginx
```

I am using 2 Slaves and 1 master Database as per the following link

[CodeIgniter configure different IP for READ and WRITE MySQL data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633692/codeigniter-configure-different-ip-for-read-and-write-mysql-data)

I am using  the following in **every controller** for making a database connection.

```
$DB1_READ = $this->load->database('READ', TRUE);

$DB2_READ = $this->load->database('READ', TRUE);

$DB3_WRITE = $this->load->database('WRITE', TRUE);
```

I am also using different READ and WRITE connections in the Database.php file:

2 READ SERVERS and 1 WRITE SERVER (MASTER)

**PROBLEM**

As I am loading Database in my controllers, WHEN I am only calling my READ Database, it's making a WRITE Connection to the WRITE server.

Where should I call `$this->load->database` so that if I am only going to EXECUTE READ query from READ database then it should not go to WRITE server causing failure of the WRITE server.

It is opening an unwanted connection at WRITE which in turn increasing Load on My Master Database. As per AWS RDS , I can only have 1 Master , so that is a HUGE issue for me as my MASTER dies Every time.

Comment: In a typical framework you would override the DAO or "driver" classes to accomplish this.  From googling it appears there is no easy solution for codeigniter.

Comment: What do you mean by the statement "it's making a WRITE Connection to the WRITE server."? Do you mean it's opening a connection to the WRITE DB which you do not want, or do you mean there are read and write requests to the server at the same time?

Comment: Yes @PeterM it is opening an unwanted connection at WRITE which in turn increasing Load on My Master Database. As per AWS RDS , I can only have 1 Master , so that is a HUGE issue for me as my MASTER dies Every time.

Comment: Ok, can I suggest loading the database in the respective function i.e. separate the read and write functionality into separate functions, then when writing, load the writable DB in the write function, and load the readable DB in the read function, and remove all loading code from the constructor (assuming that's where you are loading them from). You can even separate the functionality into read-only and write-only classes if you still wish to load the DB in the constructors automatically.